# getting value in LinkedList in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hash, linked-list

```
int index = hash(value, size);

if (array.get(index).contains(value)) {
    return false;
}
```

Arraylist.get(unknown source) is error i'm getting. What i'm doing is checking if the value exists in the linkedlist in the array index given, and if it exists return false.

Also an indexoutofbounds exception, it says "index 7: but the array size is 0"? I called the constructor with size 50 elements:

```
array = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>(50);
```

Comment: Did you actually _add_ enough elements for there to be something present at index `7`?  The `50` parameter just means that the initial size of the `ArrayList` will be 50.  It doesn't mean that there are 50 empty slots there which you can access.

Comment: oh, I see, so how do I make 50 usable spots? If I have to individually add 50 linkedlists in the array, that wouldn't work as I'd need different linklist name variables for each insert, and hard to change variable names in a for loop

Comment: `int index = hash(value, size)` are you sure it's not an `HashMap` that you need?

Comment: I'm making a hashmap from scratch using an array of linkedlists

Comment: You only added 5 elements but you are trying to access index 7, so you get this out of bounds error.

Comment: theres an error on the first insert. the hashes takes it to index 7, but the size of the array is 0. how do i allocate space for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is adding new linked lists inside the ArrayLists.

While you've created an arrayList of size 50, you haven't created instances of LinkedLists that you're trying to access.

So, in addition to what you've in the constructor, you should have something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        array.add(i, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you are trying to achieve in this.

1. Create an arraylist with embedded LinkedList.
2. Initializing the size of arraylist to 50.
   This doesn't mean that you have initialized the LinkedList inside each index of Arraylist. If you trying to access the array.get(index) it will throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. So before using this initializing the 50 LinkedList inside the Arraylist using code provided by @attaboy182 above.

   for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
       array.add(i, new LinkedList());
   }

After initializing the LinkedList you can use your code, it will not throw any error.

```
int index = 0;
List array = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>(50);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    array.add(i, new LinkedList<String>());
}
((LinkedList) array.get(index)).add("anish");
((LinkedList) array.get(index)).add("barnwal");
System.out.println(((LinkedList)array.get(index)).contains("anish"));
System.out.println(((LinkedList)array.get(index)).contains("Jakkie"));
```